# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' '

Tags: python, django, gevent

I am attempting to run `python manage.py runserver` and I am getting a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' '
```

The entirety of the output can be seen here:

```
(venv) danieljohnson@MACHPXNV2CL2Y project % python manage.py runserver
/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tzwhere/tzwhere.py:62: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  self.timezoneNamesToPolygons[tzname] = WRAP(polys)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 906, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 51, in inner_run
    http_consumer=self.get_consumer(*args, **options),
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 157, in get_consumer
    return StaticFilesConsumer()
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 347, in __init__
    self.handler = self.handler_class()
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 18, in __init__
    super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__init__()
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 194, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 56, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/Documents/code/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' '
2022-05-09T14:03:08Z <Greenlet at 0x146a6e7b0: wrapper(verbosity=1, settings=None, pythonpath=None, traceback=False, no_color=False, addrport=None, use_ipv6=False, use_threading=True, use_reloader=True, run_worker=True, use_asgi=True, http_timeout=60, websocket_handshake_timeout=5, use_static_handler=True, insecure_serving=False)> failed with ModuleNotFoundError
```

The module import code in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py =

```
def import_module(name, package=None):
    """Import a module.

    The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
    specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
    relative import to an absolute import.

    """
    level = 0
    if name.startswith('.' or ' '):
        if not package:
            msg = ("the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative "
                   "import for {!r}")
            raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
        for character in name:
            if character != '.':
                break
            level += 1
    print(name)
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

That print(name) statement prints out " .middleware"

I've tried installing/reinstalling gevent, but that didnt work. I'm lost because the package that is missing is blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show some code context? What is `WRAP`? What is the `wrapper` the Greenlet from logs holds? I haven't worked with those libs, but something is being imported by name and at some point it wasn't passed further or wasn't passed at all. We need some context to determine where you might've confused arguments or something when using lib classes.

Comment: When I print(name) - the name of the package comes up as " .middleware". I assume the error is due to the blank space preceding the .

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was essentially a typo...

I had this in my settings.py:

```
"authentication.middleware.SetDefaultUserGroupMiddleware" if not API_MODE else None,
```

Which I accidentally changed to

```
" .middleware.SetDefaultUserGroupMiddleware" if not API_MODE else None,
```

After fixing my accidental delete, all is working fine